# What is x1, x2, y1, y2, w, h of an image

Tags: jquery, image, coordinates

I'd like to know a simple thing like x1, x2, y1, y2, h, w of an image to determine manually the size of the image that i want to crop.

Is it possible to manually insert this data?

But what is x1, x2, y1, y2 ??

Comment: _Is it possible to manually insert this data?_ Simple answer is __Yes__

Comment: Grab the position, width and height, and off you go.

Comment: There are several dublicate questions for this, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885144/how-to-get-current-position-of-an-image-in-jquery etc etc etc

Comment: _What is x1, x2, y1, y2?_ They are coordinates See [__DEMO__](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=handler)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current position of an image in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885144/how-to-get-current-position-of-an-image-in-jquery)